# VBS to extract nodes from all xml documents in a directory

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have the below VBS, which pulls out two attributes from one piece of xml, I would like to modify the code to look in the data directory and pull out these two attributes for all xml documents within in.

Would also be neat if it could put the output from each file on the same row.

Username - ID rather than the current

Username

ID

```
 Set objXML2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXML2.async = "false"
    strdir="c:\temp\XML\Data\test.xml"
    If (Not objXML2.load(strdir)) Then
        wscript.echo "Unable to load file '" & strdir & "'. "
        WScript.Quit(1)
    End If
    Set colNodes1 = objXML2.selectNodes ("/User/Username") 
    For Each objNode in colNodes1
        wscript.echo objnode.getAttribute("name") & objNode.text 
    NEXT
    Set colNodes2 = objXML2.selectNodes ("/User/ID") 
    For Each objNode in colNodes2 
        wscript.echo objnode.getAttribute("name") & objNode.text

    NEXT
```

Small example of xml, will be different tags but format will be the same.

```
<Batch>
 <User>
  <Username>Ignatius</Username>
  <Department>IT</Department>
  <ID>123456</ID>
 </User>
</Batch>
```

How could I also pull out the Town from the below XML? Onto the same row? And also put it into a text file?

```
<Batch>
<User>
 <Detail> 
   <Username>Ignatius</Username>
   <Department>IT</Department>
   <ID>123456</ID>
 </Detail>
 <Location>
   <Town>London</Town>
 </Location>
</User>
</Batch>
```

Comment: please post a (smal) sample of your .XML.

Comment: so why do you ask for *attribute* retrieval??

Comment: Hi @Ekkehard.Horner please see xml example above. There will be lots of files in directory in same format (unknown as yet how many a day) need to extract data from all the files into a text document. So from the above example on one line would be: Ignatius_123456

Answer (score 0):

Key concepts:

1. loop over .Files of a folder
2. filter for specific files
3. .selectNodes for a list of desired nodes
4. .selectSingleNode for single nodes (surprise!)

As used here:

```
  Dim oFS    : Set oFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim objXML : Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  objXML.async = false
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder("..\data").Files
      WScript.Echo oFile.Path
      If 1 = InStr(oFile.Name, "24607266") Then
          objXML.load oFile.Path
          If objXML.parseError Then ' never without my check
             WScript.Echo objXML.parseError.reason
          Else
             Dim sXPath : sXPath = "/Batch/User"
             Dim ndlUsers : Set ndlUsers = objXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
             If 0 = ndlUsers.length Then ' never without my check
                WScript.Echo "fail:", sXPath
             Else
                Dim ndUser
                For Each ndUser In ndlUsers
                    ' no attribs!
                    ' WScript.Echo ndUser.getAttribute("Name"), ndUser.getAttribute("Id")
                    WScript.Echo ndUser.selectSingleNode("Username").text, ndUser.selectSingleNode("ID").text
                Next
             End If
          End If
      End If
  Next
```

(Start your research [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

Comment: @user3811820 - if your 'new' problem is so different from the solved one that you can't work it out following the principles just learned, it deserves its own question.